# How do I get a context variable into a template tag in django - modifying Wagtail Menus template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

I'm modifying the Wagtail Menus flatmenu template tag to accept a context variable instead of a string for the handle. The use case is that I want to pull in a specific menu based on a slugified version of a user's group name.

The template looks like this:

```
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
    {% with handle=group.name|slugify %}
       {% utility_flat_menu handle %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

The templaet tags looks like:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def utility_flat_menu(
    context, handle, max_levels=None, show_menu_heading=False,
    apply_active_classes=False, allow_repeating_parents=True,
    show_multiple_levels=True, template='', sub_menu_template='',
    sub_menu_templates=None, fall_back_to_default_site_menus=None,
    use_absolute_page_urls=False, add_sub_menus_inline=None, *args, 
    **kwargs
):
    validate_supplied_values('flat_menu', max_levels=max_levels)

    if fall_back_to_default_site_menus is None:
        fall_back_to_default_site_menus = settings.FLAT_MENUS_FALL_BACK_TO_DEFAULT_SITE_MENUS

    if not show_multiple_levels:
        max_levels = 1

    menu_class = settings.models.FLAT_MENU_MODEL
    return menu_class.render_from_tag(
        context=context,
        handle=context,
        fall_back_to_default_site_menus=fall_back_to_default_site_menus,
        max_levels=max_levels,
        apply_active_classes=apply_active_classes,
        allow_repeating_parents=allow_repeating_parents,
        use_absolute_page_urls=use_absolute_page_urls,
        add_sub_menus_inline=add_sub_menus_inline,
        template_name=template,
        sub_menu_template_name=sub_menu_template,
        sub_menu_template_names=split_if_string(sub_menu_templates),
        show_menu_heading=show_menu_heading,
        **kwargs
    )
```

That tag is a replacement for teh Wagtail Menus Flat Menu template tag found here: https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus/blob/1a938576adb801c455bea4b64906fb135c89f65f/wagtailmenus/templatetags/menu_tags.py#L46

So, what I'm trying to do is allow the handle to accept a context variable. I can for the life of me figure out how to get that to work. What you see for the `handle = context` is my guess at where the change needs to go, but I'm guessing.

Comment: Is `handle=context['some_variable_name']` what you're looking for...?

Comment: I believe so! Testing it now.